# Rewarded video ads events not firing in Unity and Admob

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I am using Unity 2019.2.8f1 and I am preparing to publish my first game on Google Play Store. Unfortunately the reward is not being given to the user after watching a rewarded ad. The user should get an extra life whenever he/she watches a rewarded ad.

Here is my Ad Manager script. I am using dummy ids for testing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public static AdManager instance;
private string AppId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
private BannerView banner;
private string bannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
private InterstitialAd videoAD;
private string videoID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
private int showing, video;
private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardedAds;
private string rewardedID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
public bool RewardTaken;




public void HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed event received");
    RequestRewardedAD();


}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{

    UIManager.variable.RewardPanel.SetActive(true);
    UIManager.variable.gameOver.SetActive(false);
}


private void Awake()
{

   rewardedAds = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    showing = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("show");
    video = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("video");

    MobileAds.Initialize(AppId);
    RequestvideoAD();

    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(this);
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    RewardTaken = false;
    if (video == 1)
    {
        ShowvideoAD();

    }


    if (showing == 1)
    {
        requestBanner();

    }
    RequestRewardedAD();

    // Called when the user should be rewarded for watching a video.
    rewardedAds.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    // Called when the ad is closed.
    rewardedAds.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardBasedVideoClosed;


}

public void requestBanner()
{
    banner = new BannerView(bannerID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    banner.LoadAd(request);
    banner.Show();
}


public void RequestvideoAD()
{
    videoAD = new InterstitialAd(videoID);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    videoAD.LoadAd(request);


}
public void ShowvideoAD()
{
    if (videoAD.IsLoaded())
    {
        videoAD.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("FullscreenADNotLoaded");

    }

}
public void RequestRewardedAD()
{
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    rewardedAds.LoadAd(request,rewardedID);
}
public void ShowRewardedAD()
{
    if(rewardedAds.IsLoaded())
    {
        rewardedAds.Show();
        Debug.Log("Ads Are Working");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Rewarded Ads not laded properly");
    }
}

public void HideAD()
{
    banner.Hide();
}


}
```

Even though the console was not showing any message that I wanted to show as a part of the test. After trying several times, I decided to remove the debug text.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attaching Callbacks to a different ad object and you are loading ads from a different object.

Try using rewardedAds

to Load Ad

```
public void RequestvideoAD()
{
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    rewardedAds.LoadAd(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me but it doesn't seem to work out

Comment: Did you try using the global ad object? i.e. "rewardedAds".
And what log do you get? 
Ads Are Working OR Rewarded Ads not laded properly